# Sqlite extension is not working as expected

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am working on an WinRT app. I want to use `sqlite-net-extensions` to support `OneToMany`, `ManyToMany`.

```
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using SQLite;

[Table("WorkFlow")]
public class Workflow
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    [OneToMany]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}

[Table("Step")]
public class Step
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to generate the tables for the database, it raises the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   app_name.exe but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [app_name.Model.modelName]

This is coming from the `SqlType` in `SQLite.cs`.

But from the example on the `sqlite-net-extensions` [homepage](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), `List` property should work fine.

This is a copy of their example:

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, the [SQLite.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/0b1a7966c12a7a2135632a79cbe5266db98c672c/Todo/SharedProject/Todo/Data/SQLite.cs) type parsing method: `string SqlType(TableMapping.Column p, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks)` has no interpretation of the List type so it throws the NotSupportedException. I tried using nuget and by adding the source (and its reference) of SQLiteNetExtensions without luck... Anybody?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm stuck with the same issue

Comment: Nevermind, @redent84 gave the answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is usually an installation issue caused because SQLite-Net Extensions was compiled using a SQLite-Net library but you are running your App using another. You can try adding the [PCL NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/) package to your project or you can download [the sources from Git](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src) and reference the project directly.

Comment: What's a good way of determining whether I've got the right package(s) installed? I have the same problem as OP, still unresolved, and these are my installed SQLite packages: SQLite.Net.Core-PCL, SQLite.Net-PCL, SQLiteNetExtensions, sqlite-net-pcl, SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green, SQLitePCLRaw.core, SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android, SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android, SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3.ios_unified.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson 'sqlite-net-pcl' and 'SQLite.Net.Core-PCL' are conflicting packages. Make sure to use the latest alpha version of SQLite-Net Extensions and remove any other sqlite.net pcl reference

Comment: Thank you! I'll be trying to get that to work now. I had thought that maybe something like that was going on, but when Iooked at SQLite-Net-PCL I noticed it listed SQLite.Net.Core-PCL as a dependency. That doesn't sound like they should be in conflict?

Comment: Okay, so I removed all the packages I mentioned above, and then re-installed SQLiteNetExtensions (and it added the two packages mentioned first). But now my DbConnection constructor does not accept one parameter, so I guess I need some of those other packages too. Should I ínstall all of them, except for the one called "sqlite-net-pcl"?

Answer (score 3):

Try giving *Table* (**Step**) a **Primary Key** and a **Foreign Key** referencing *Table* (**WorkFlow**)

```
[Table("Step")]
public class Step
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int StepId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(WorkFlow))]
    public int WorkFlowId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne]
    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Uninstall all references to any SQLite NuGet packages from all projects, in my case this was a Xamarin.Forms solution. Clean the solution as an extra precaution (you could even check the packages are uninstalled from the packages folder just in case there's a file access issue blocking the delete). Install again by searching for SQLiteNetExtensions (not sqlite-net-pcl) and checking that the 'Include prerelease' option is selected in Visual Studio (tested on 2017). This will install sqlite-net-pcl v1.2.0 as the minimum dependency and several files including the word 'Raw'. You can test at this point to check the 'Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1' error. For me, this disappeared. It should now be safe to update sqlite-net-pcl to the latest version, which at time of writing is v1.3.3.

Background:
I encountered the same issue with the following combination:

1. sqlite-net-pcl v1.3.3
2. SQLiteNetExtensions v2.0.0-alpha2

In my first attempt I installed sqlite-net-pcl first through NuGet and then installed the latest stable version of SQLiteNetExtensions. After discovering the extensions are not compatible with sqlite-net-pcl I then updated to the latest pre-release version. I encountered the same 'Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1' bug and found it very confusing leading me to try other things first and question if I'd made a mistake. Cleaning the project, deleting the packages (from the folder) and restoring did not work for me. I didn't check the packages config but using the NuGet manager and comparing to a test project everything was the same. Uninstalling everything as mentioned in my fix and letting SQLiteNetExtensions do the dependency checking for me fixed the problem. I think there was a problem buried in the NuGet files from having the wrong version of SQLiteNetExtensions initially.

P.S. Earlier in the day NuGet downloaded two packages for a fresh Xamarin.Forms project with 0KB file size that was installed in a typical way and I had to copy them in from another project. I don't normally get NuGet related issues.