# Using SQLite-Net Extensions and OneToMany relation

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm having difficulty trying to implement an SQLite-Extensions example for Windows Phone 8.1 that features a OneToMany relation. I'd really like to use this feature but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463849/sqlite-extension-is-not-working-as-expected), when I try to use the [provided example](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/overview) for a Stocks table that has a List of Valuations:

```
public class Stock
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(8)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]      // One to many relationship with Valuation
    public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuation
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Stock
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

and I try to create the table I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in app_name.exe but was not handled in user code Additional information: Don't know about >System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [app_name.Model.modelName]

I had initially included a NuGet package reference to sqlite-net as well as SQLiteNetExtensions-PCL but it was previously mentioned that this is due to the wrong version of sqlite-net being referenced.

However I've tried downloading the source for sqlite-net and building this locally and it doesn't get referenced directly by SQLiteNetExtensions.

I've included the source locally in my solution as well it doesn't seem to make a difference. Would anybody have any further suggestions? I haven't come across any downloadable example for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added a reference to SQLiteNetExtensions-PCL, you do NOT also need to manually add a reference to SQLite from VS/Add References as the Nuget package includes the correct version for you.

Comment: I did actually manage to get the extensions working. The solution is that you do NOT also need to manually add a reference to SQLite from VS/Add References as the Nuget package includes the correct version for you.